# Javascript check if pincode has 4 digits

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a javascript that checks if you entered 4 digits but I'm getting an error saying break is an illegal statement. I'm new to loops and strings so I don't see the error.

```
var pin = "";
var lengte =0;

while(true)
{
    pin = prompt("voer hier je pincode in");
    lengte = pin.lenght;
    document.write(lengte);
    if (lengte == 4){break}
    alert("U heeft geen pincode ingevoerd");
}
alert('ok');
```

Comment: You can use the regex, `/^\d{4}$/.test(pin)`

Comment: what about a for loop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the spelling of your code. The loop is named `while` not `whilte` and the length-property is `length` not `lenght`.